# Azure Pipelines artifact download from Azure Artifacts stopped working

Tags: download, azure-pipelines, httprequest, publish, azure-artifacts

I have set up a pair of Azure pipelines such successful completion of the first pipeline triggers the second pipeline. The first pipeline publishes a small JSON file to Azure Artifacts, and then the second pipeline downloads the JSON file.

Here are the two pipelines.

Pipeline one:

```
# Pipeline one

trigger:
- '*'

pool:
  name: 'Default'
  demands:
  # I use this property to make sure it runs on the correct build agent
  - Can_do_builds -equals true

steps:
- script: |
    echo This is Pipeline One.
    echo Running on $(Agent.MachineName)
    echo Running in $(Pipeline.Workspace)
  displayName: 'Display Pipeline One info'

- powershell: |
    $json = @"
    {
        'build_id': '$(Build.BuildID)',
        'build_number': '$(Build.BuildNumber)',
        'build_type': '$(Build.Reason)',
        'source_repo': '$(Build.Repository.Name)',
        'source_branch': '$(Build.SourceBranchName)',
        'source_commit_id': '$(Build.SourceVersion)'
    }
    "@
    $f = '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dropfile.json'
    Add-Content -Path $f -Value $json
    Write-Host Contents of $f
    Write-Host "================"
    Get-Content $f
  displayName: Create the dropfile

- publish: dropfile.json
  artifact: theDropfile
  displayName: Publish the dropfile
```

Pipeline two:

```
# Pipeline two

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'Default'
  demands:
  # I use this property to make sure it runs on the other build agent
  - Can_do_integration_tests -equals true

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline-one
    source: my_workspace.pipeline-one
    trigger:
      enabled: true
      branches:
        include:
        - master
        - develop
        - release_*
        - passing-info-btwn-pipelines

steps:
- script: |
    echo This is Pipeline Two.
    echo Running on $(Agent.MachineName)
    echo Running in $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    echo Build reason is $(Build.Reason)
    echo Triggering resource is $(Resources.TriggeringAlias)
    echo Triggering category is $(Resources.TriggeringCategory)
  displayName: 'Display Pipeline Two info'

# - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
#   displayName: Download the dropfile
#   inputs:
#     source: 'specific'
#     project: 'QA'
#     pipeline: 'my_workspace.pipeline-one' # if it will accept strings
#     # pipeline: 12 # if it won't accept strings
#     preferTriggeringPipeline: 'true'
#     runVersion: 'latest'
#     artifact: theDropfile
#     path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/'

- download: pipeline-one
  artifact: theDropfile
  patterns: '**/*.json'
  displayName: Download the dropfile the other way

- powershell: |
      $f = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/dropfile.json"
      if( Test-Path $f ) {
        Get-Content $f
      } else {
        Write-Host '$f not found'
      }
  displayName: Read the dropfile
```

Everything worked fine until our IT gang did two things:

1. Removed Just-In-Time.
2. Added our two VMs (self-hosted VMs, running Windows Server 2016 I think) to our `companyname.local` domain.

Pipeline one (the publishing one) still works. Every run publishes the artifact. I can verify that by navigating through the build log to the artifact link and downloading it.

But pipeline two (the downloading one) doesn't work anymore. It tries for 18 minutes to download the artifact, and then gives up. The logfile doesn't give much information, but it looks like the Azure Artifacts server is rejecting the agent's HTTP request. The entire contents of the logfile are as follows:

```
Starting: Download the dropfile the other way
==============================================================================
Task         : Download pipeline artifact
Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
Version      : 1.198.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
==============================================================================
Download from the specified build: #4927
Download artifact to: E:\acmbuild1\_work\5/pipeline-one/theDropfile
Using default max parallelism.
Max dedup parallelism: 192
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
Minimatch patterns: [**/*.json]
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
Minimatch patterns: [**/*.json]
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
Minimatch patterns: [**/*.json]
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
Minimatch patterns: [**/*.json]
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 05a9e36f-885e-4a2b-9944-a4cfa8cc11f3
##[error]No such host is known.
Finishing: Download the dropfile the other way
```

At first I thought that the failure was with the `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` task, which is why I tried using the `download` task instead. But I believe they're both the same code under the hood. In any case, the failure mode and the error message are the same.

What is causing the download failure? How can I fix it -- or how can the IT team fix it?

Answer (score 1):

“No such host is known“ from your logfile seems like that the VMs added to your company domain can’t access to Azure DevOps.

You may ask IT teams to  add certain Ips and URLs to allowlist.  Comman domain urls(e.g)  `dev.azure.com` and `*.dev.azure.com`

please refer to doc:[Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#domain-urls-to-allow)

Comment: Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.